# Convert KB To MB using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I use a command to get the size of a remote folder, after it's run it returns

```
120928312 http://blah.com
```

The number is size in **bytes**. What I'd like to do is have it output in **MB**, and the `http` part removed. I'm guessing greping to a file but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it with shell builtins

```
some_command | while read KB dummy;do echo $((KB/1024))MB;done
```

Here is a more useful version:

```
#!/bin/sh
human_print(){
while read B dummy; do
  [ $B -lt 1024 ] && echo ${B} bytes && break
  KB=$(((B+512)/1024))
  [ $KB -lt 1024 ] && echo ${KB} kilobytes && break
  MB=$(((KB+512)/1024))
  [ $MB -lt 1024 ] && echo ${MB} megabytes && break
  GB=$(((MB+512)/1024))
  [ $GB -lt 1024 ] && echo ${GB} gigabytes && break
  echo $(((GB+512)/1024)) terabytes
done
}

echo 120928312 http://blah.com | human_print
```

Comment: @Lurch If you don't want the Mb just remove it from the command

Comment: what i meant was its calculating it wrong, the output of some_command is 121013231 which is in KB when I do some_command your_command I get 118176Mb which is wrong.

Comment: @Lurch what exactly do you think it should be?

Comment: sorry i've made a misatke the output from some_command is returned in Bytes not KB.

Comment: @technosaurus Fixed! But after that change, I think I might also need to adjust some of the answers to reflect that change.

Answer (score 12):

How about this line:

```
$ echo "120928312 http://blah.com" | awk '{$1/=1024;printf "%.2fMB\n",$1}'
118094.05MB
```

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtins (display an integer like the KB version)

```
var="120928312 http://blah.com"
echo "$(( ${var%% *} / 1024)) MB"
```

Comment: don't forget that shell uses integer math, so (X+512)/1024 to get proper rounding ... I ignored this part in my answer too

Answer (score 6):

```
function bytes_for_humans {
    local -i bytes=$1;
    if [[ $bytes -lt 1024 ]]; then
        echo "${bytes}B"
    elif [[ $bytes -lt 1048576 ]]; then
        echo "$(( (bytes + 1023)/1024 ))KiB"
    else
        echo "$(( (bytes + 1048575)/1048576 ))MiB"
    fi
}

$ bytes_for_humans 1
1 Bytes
$ bytes_for_humans 1024
1KiB
$ bytes_for_humans 16777216
16MiB
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `bc` and `printf`

[`bc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html) and `printf` can be used to show the output with a configurable number of decimal places, also grouping digits:

```
$ KB=1234567890
$ echo "$KB / 1000" | bc -l | xargs -i printf "%'.1f MB" {}
1,234,567.9 MB
```

#### Using `numfmt`

To use [`numfmt`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) to auto-scale the output unit:

```
$ numfmt --from=iec --to=si 123456789K
127G
$ numfmt --from=si --to=iec 123456789K
115G
```

To use [`numfmt`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) to output to a fixed unit, e.g. `M`:

```
$ numfmt --from=iec --to-unit=1M --grouping 123456789K
126,420

$ numfmt --from=si --to-unit=1Mi --grouping 123456789K
117,738
```

See its man page and ensure it is used correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work if the number is greater than 1024 megabytes because it will print the size in gigabytes instead.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin I have now updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `awk`

```
awk '{MB=$1/1024; print $MB}'
```

`$1` - value of the first column, size (KB) in this case

Comment: note you can also just print it directly. e.g. in a pipe: `... | awk '{print($1/1024)}' | ...`

Answer (score 0):

Github: [index0-b-to-mb.sh](https://github.com/EvilRedHorse/conversion/blob/master/index0-b-to-mb.sh)

#### index0-b-to-mb.sh

```
    #! /bin/bash --posix

    # requirements: vim-common
    # sudo dnf -y install vim-common

    function b_to_mb {
      # get BASE conversion type
      if [ "$3" = "BASE10" ]; then
        # set for BASE10
        BASE_DIV=1000000
      else
          if [ "$3" = "MIXED" ]; then
          # set for MIXED
          BASE_DIV=1024000
          else
          # set default for BASE2
          BASE_DIV=1048576
          fi
      fi
      # create array from string
      # use bc with 6 digit precision to calculate megabytes from bytes
      ARRAY=($1) && printf "scale=6; ${ARRAY[0]}/$BASE_DIV\n" | bc -l
    }
    # execute b_to_mb
    b_to_mb $1 $2
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte#Definitions

`./index0-b-to-mb.sh '120928312 http://blah.com' MIXED`

```
118.094054
```

`./index0-b-to-mb.sh '120928312 http://blah.com' BASE10`

```
120.928312
```

`./index0-b-to-mb.sh '120928312 http://blah.com' BASE2`

```
115.326225
```

`./index0-b-to-mb.sh '120928312 http://blah.com'`

```
115.326225
```

`./index0-b-to-mb.sh "$(your_command)"`

```
115.326225
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small routine I wrote that relies only on bash, and will format any decimal byte value above 1000 into an estimate in terms of K (1024), M (1024K), G (1024M), T, Peta, Exa.  It rounds to the nearest tenth.  The original purpose was to constrain an output to a fixed number of digits, 6, to mimic the output of the `pv` command.  Use only for estimation purposes, e.g., KB/sec transfer rates.

```
gmk_fmt () { # bytes
  # Apply a suffix to any byte value greater than 999.  Returns a string w/len at most 6 
  # (f5.1 + modifier) with the appropriate modifier, K, M, G, T, P, E.
  # Example: gb_fmt 370220929180 returns 344.7G
  b=$1
  d=0
  s="EPTGMK "
  while [ $b -ge 1000 ] ; do
    d=$(((($((($b & 1023)))*100/1024)+5)/10))   # remainder mod 1024, rnd to nearest tenth
    b=$(( ($b ) >> 10 ))                        # divide by 1024
    s=${s:: -1}                                 # advance the prefix
  done
  [ $d -ge 10 ] && { let b++ ; d=0; }           # if rem is ".10," then bump the top unit
  [ $d -gt 0 ] && suf=".$d"                     # apply decimal only if not a zero
  echo ${b}${suf}${s: -1}
}
```

Here is some test code to drive it.  As written, it will generate random values and conversions. Change "false" to "true" for an incremental test to verify rounding:

```
let i=800
while [ $i -lt 1200 ] ; do
  if false ; then
    printf "%8s %s\n" $(gmk_fmt $i) $(bc<<<"scale=2; $i/1024")
  else
    n=$(($RANDOM * ( 1024 ** ($RANDOM & 3))))
    printf "%8s %s\n" $(gmk_fmt $n) $n
  fi
  let i++
done
```