# Convert B to KiB, MiB calling a bash function

Tags: bash, function

In this script I'm using to check the size of a given mailbox, the size is returned in Byte. Would be much more easy in a "human readable" format.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059944/kb-to-mb-using-bash) question is great but it is starting to get old and I am not able to modify the answers for my needs.

Having:

```
MAILBOX="/var/mail/$1
GOOD=471859200 #450MB
ACTUALSIZE=$(wc -c <"$MAILBOX")
MAILBOXDIM=$(grep "mailbox_size_limit" /etc/postfix/main.cf | awk -F" " '{print $3}')
```

I need to print the value in KB / MB

```
if [ ! -f $MAILBOX ]; then
  echo "Can't check the size of $MAILBOX | Size=0; Total=$MAILBOXDIM"
  exit 3
else
  if [ $ACTUALSIZE -lt $GOOD ]; then
    echo "Size of mailbox is $ACTUALSIZE | Size=$ACTUALSIZE; Total=$MAILBOXDIM"
    exit 0
  fi
fi
```

Well, the code is much longer but more or less it is the same.

**I'd need something like**

```
echo "Size of mailbox is convert($ACTUALSIZE) | Size=convert($ACTUALSIZE); Total=convert($MAILBOXDIM)"
```

and I'm not able to write the correct function

**EDIT:**
Thanks everybody! If you or anybody in the future is wondering why I need 2 variables to achieve the same result

```
ACTUALSIZE=$(wc -c <"$MAILBOX")
ASIZE=$(convert "$ACTUALSIZE")
echo $ASIZE
```

is because I use the IF to compare the values. ASIZE is "450Mib" and IF doesn't like letters.

To solve this rather use 2 variables:

```
GOOD=450
  if [ $ACTUALSIZE -lt $GOOD ]; then
    echo "Size is $ASIZE"
  fi
```

Or use awk, then:

```
ASIZE=$(convert $(wc -c <"$MAILBOX") | awk -F"MiB" '{print $1}')
  if [ $ASIZE -lt $GOOD ]; then
    echo "Size "$ASIZE"MiB"
  fi
```

Or read the manual:
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) about suffix and iec / iec-i

Comment: Coreutils v8.21 added `numfmt`; `printf "%s\n" "12345678" | numfmt --to=iec`

Comment: thanks for this! didn't see it before. I'm trying to test this one too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
convert() { numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B "$@"; }
```

Comment: Looks what I am lookin for, thank you! but when I applied it In the script and echoed:
 echo "Size of mailbox is "convert $ACTUALSIZE "
the result is "Size of mailbox is convert 465794232"
How would you use it?

Comment: @Nihvel With command substitution: `echo "Size of mailbox is $(convert "$size")"` or my preferred `printf "Size of mailbox is %s\n" "$(convert "$size")"`

Comment: Thank you! fast and easy, I found this easier to insert in my script.
Used a new $VAR=$(convert "$ACTUALSIZE") and echoed $VAR. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use expr like:

```
expr $ACTUALSIZE / 1024
expr $ACTUALSIZE \* 1024
```

To go down or up in units.

Also You can use it directly in echo:

```
echo $(expr $ACTUALSIZE / 1024)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to insert this code in the script because from cli it works. Do you think is there a way to even make the echo more flexible? like not writing $(expr $ACTUALSIZE / 1024) on every row but something like calling a function or editing the main VAR ?

Comment: Yes, You can edit the main var like: 
ACTUALSIZE=$(expr $ACTUALSIZE / 1024)

Comment: Alright that's great! I don't really understand though, how should I edit the main ACTUALSIZE? I'm already using it to store the wc -c command.
As you've noticed I'm not skilled at developing and I find it difficult to implement your solution (+1 anyway because I like this command)

Comment: It's not storing the command, but the command's output.
Everything in $( ) gets normally executed: try "echo $(echo 'Inception - WHAAM BAAAM !')" to understand it better.
And please accept one of the answers. :)

Comment: Thanks mate for your help, what you provided me works pretty good but I needed it to be easy to insert. Another solution matched better what I was looking thou your was really close ;)
and yesss I know about $() but wasn't sure if VAR=$(expr $ACTUALSIZE / 1024) and echo $VAR.. was the best way. At the end I chose for another solution with numfmt which is better for these cases.

Comment: That's very good. I didn't say to accept MY answer. I'm glad to help Bro! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Some functions to convert to int or float :

```
to_kb_int() {
  echo $(( $1 / 1024 ))
}

to_mb_int() {
  to_kb_int $(( $1 / 1024 ))
}

to_kb_dec() {
  echo "scale=2; $1/1024" | bc
}

to_mb_dec() {
  echo "scale=2;  $(to_kb_dec "$1")/1024"| bc
}

to_kb_int 2048
to_mb_int 6148728 

to_kb_dec 2048
to_mb_dec 6148728
```

Output :

```
2
5
2.00
5.86
```

Comment: sweet! first I need to solve the function or expr part and then a conversion to int or float could be handy ;)